# JS transform deeply nested array of objects at the top level with renaming

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I would like to simplify this nested array of objects move some items at the top level with a new property name. Given this data:

```
let data = [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "model": "Lemon",
        "length": "4",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 38,
            "kind": "D",
            "color": "Gray",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "model": "Botanica",
        "length": "2",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 39,
            "kind": "A",
            "color": "Yellow",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 40,
            "kind": "B",
            "color": "Green",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 2
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ];
```

My desired output:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "model": "Lemon",
        "color": "Gray",
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "model": "Botanica",
        "color": "Yellow",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "model": "Botanica",
        "color": "Green",
      }
    ]
```

Or much better to combine the model and color:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "model": "Lemon - Gray"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "model": "Botanica - Yellow"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "model": "Botanica - Green"
  }
]
```

If there are multiple specifics, it would also create a new object together with the model and color, then it would move at the top. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
const result = data.map(({ details, ...d }) => ({
  ...d,
  data: details.map(({ specifics, ...s }) => ({
    ...r,
    id: specifics.id
  }))
}));
```

But it seems that I can't get the right result. How to simplify this one? Thanks.

Comment: `const result = data.flatMap(({ details, model }) => {
  return details.map(({ specifics, color }) => {
    return { id: specifics.id, color, model }
  })
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to loop through the data array. We can get the `model` from the data element namely `item`. Then we need to loop through that `item.details` array. From that we can get `id`, `detail.color`. Hers's the full code.

```js
let data = [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "model": "Lemon",
        "length": "4",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 38,
            "kind": "D",
            "color": "Gray",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "model": "Botanica",
        "length": "2",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 39,
            "kind": "A",
            "color": "Yellow",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 40,
            "kind": "B",
            "color": "Green",
            "specifics": {
              "id": 2
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ];

const result = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  return [...result, ...item.details.map((detail) => {
    return {
      id: detail.specifics.id,
      model: item.model + " - " + detail.color
    }
  } )]
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is working correctly. Thanks for taking the time to answer!